# android manifest permission don't work

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Good Afternoon all !

I had a issue with Android Studio 2.3. I try to make an app than can read contact but it looks that when I try to install the app there is no premission required...May be I miss something ?

My AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.unedesep">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

    </activity>

</application>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: yes, it wilk never work unless yoi request runtime permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your testing device is api 23 and above i.e. marshmallow and above. In this case you need to request runtime permission. Please go through below link

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! How can I change my testing device ?

Comment: if you are using emulator, then download one of lollipop or kitkat to test. If phone then look for phone of version below 6